# ASP.Net Identity MVC 5 Creating Membership Tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have created a new application & When i run my application using `ASP.Net Identity`, I get automatic created tables `ASPNetRoles, ASPNetUserClaims`, etc.

My requirement is when a new company is registered, all these tables should be created for that company.

For e.g A company with name GLOBAL registers then all membership tables should be created as `GLOBAL_ASPNetRoles, GLOBAL_ASPNetUserClaims,` etc.

As i am new to this, have no idea How to do this?

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

Identity uses EntityFramework to map types to tables. Check out this link to configure the IdentityDbContext to change the table names for Identity classes

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/JJ591617.aspx